# Counting non-repeating matching pairs in a Java array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm new to java, and through my searches have found numerous posts on ALMOST what I'm looking for but not quite.
I'm trying to use elementary java techniques to count the number of UNIQUE times a number has a match.
For instance the array {2,3,2,3,2} would have two unique matching pair cases (2,2) and (3,3)
So far (see below code) all I can seem to come up with is a count of how many TOTAL mached pairs there are. in the example case the result would be four cases (2,2), (2,2), (3,3), (2,2). To be clear this is 1st semester problem type stuff, so I **can't** use Map or more advanced techniques. Simple loops with counts and iterations. Thanks

```
int count = 0;
    for( int i=0;i<=hand.length-2 ;i++)
    {
        for( int j=i+1;j<=hand.length-1;j++)
        {
            if (hand[j] == hand[i])
            {

                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Are there reasonable bounds on the numbers?  Like, they're all integers between 1 and 100 or something?

Comment: I don't think you actually need to construct all pairs to solve your problem, if it is only a count you are after. If you transform your array to a `Map<Integer, Integer>`  that maps an entry to the number of occurrences, then `floor(count / 2)` should give the number of pairs for each number no?

Comment: for more context, in this particular situation I'm limited to an array of five values ranging from 1-9. Also trying to solve with elementary techniques such as loops as I have not yet progressed into  more advanced topics

Comment: Oh, is this a homework problem? What exactly are you allowed to use? Are you allowed to modify the array?

Comment: Precisely. Just getting my feet wet in java, so while all these answers using Map look fantastic... I am limited to 1st semester Java type techniques.I should have been more clear in original post. No modifying or sorting the array. We are allowed to use loops and counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@azurefrog gives a good answer already. Here is an implementation that counts pairs that have more than 3 entries for a given number:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 9);
Map<Integer, Long> map = numbers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(num -> num, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue() / 2));

// output
map.forEach((num, count) -> System.out.println(String.format("%d has %d unique pairs", num, count)));
Long total = map.values().stream().reduce((acc, c) -> c + acc).get();
System.out.print(String.format("A total of %d pairs", total));
```

Taking into account your other constraints listed in the comments: no modifing original data, simple loops, only 'simple' data structures;

One method would be to track whether you have seen an element before (I do this with a boolean array):

```
int[] hand = {2,3,2,3,2,9,5,5,5,5,5,5,5};
boolean[] hasPair = new boolean[10];
for(int i = 0; i <= hand.length - 2 ; i++) {
    for(int j= i + 1; j <= hand.length - 1; j++) {
        if (hand[j] == hand[i]) {
            hasPair[hand[j]] = true;
        }
    }
}
int count = 0;
for (boolean b : hasPair) {
    if (b) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
System.out.print(count);
```

This counts unique pairs or 'duplicates', assumes that input array is of int in {1, ..., 9}

Answer (score 1):

**Java 8**

If you can use Java 8, it's pretty simple to use to the streams API to group up elements and check how many of them belong to at least one pair:

```
    Integer[] data = { 2, 3, 2, 3, 2 };

    // create a map of each value to a list containing all instances of that value in the array
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = Arrays.stream(data).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i));

    // count how many of those lists have more than one element, i.e. pairs
    long uniquePairs = map.values().stream().filter(l -> l.size() > 1).count();

    System.out.println(uniquePairs);
```

---

**Java 7**

If you're stuck using Java 7, it's a little more complicated, but you can create a map that contains elements as keys and a count of how many times they appear in the array as values.  Then you can traverse the values of the map looking for elements that occur at least twice (i.e. belong to at least one pair):

```
    Integer[] data = { 2, 3, 2, 3, 2 };

    // create a map of each element to a count of the times that element appears in the array
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i : data) {
        Integer oldCount = map.get(i);
        int newCount = oldCount == null ? 1 : oldCount + 1;
        map.put(i, newCount);
    }

    // count the number of elements that appear more than once, i.e. pairs
    int uniquePairs = 0;
    for (int i : map.values()) {
        if (i > 1) uniquePairs++;
    }

    System.out.println(uniquePairs);
```

Comment: I don't think this will account for pairs where entry counts are greater than 3, eg: {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3} - should this be 3 pairs according to problem spec?

Comment: The way I read the question, {2,2,2,2,3,3} would be 2 unique pairs, (2,2) and (3,3).

Comment: good looking solution, unfortunately I cant use Map. See revised post. thanks!

Comment: Instead of a Map, you could just use an `int[] counts = new int[10];` and increment the value at the index corresponding to the element of the input array in the first loop.  It's the same basic logic as using a Map.